# Converting list column to string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df called `df` like so. The tag_position is either a string or list. but I want them to be all strings. How can i do this? I also want to remove the white space at the end.

input

```
id  tag_positions
1   center
2   right
3   ['left']
4   ['center ']
5   [' left']
6   ['right']
7   left
```

expected output

```
id  tag_positions
1   center
2   right
3   left
4   center
5   left
6   right
7   left
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `explode` and then `strip`:

```
df.tag_positions = df.tag_positions.explode().str.strip()
```

to get

```
   id tag_positions
0   1        center
1   2         right
2   3          left
3   4        center
4   5          left
5   6         right
6   7          left
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join:

```
df['tag_positions'].map(''.join)
```

Or:

```
df['tag_positions'].str.join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `str` chain with `np.where`

```
df['tag_positions'] = np.where(df['tag_positions'].map(lambda x : type(x).__name__)=='list',df['tag_positions'].str[0],df['tag_positions'])
```

Also my favorite `explode`

```
df = df.explode('tag_positions')
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the ones that aren't a list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and check if an `item` is an instance of a `list`, if yes, take the first element. and then you can just use `str.strip` to strip off the unwanted spaces.

```py
df['tag_positions'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x).str.strip()
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
Out[42]: 
0    center
1     right
2      left
3    center
4      left
5     right
6      left
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert with apply method like this

```
df.tag_positions = df.tag_positions.apply(lambda x : ''.join(x) if type(x) == list else x)
```

if all the lists have a length of 1 you can do this also:

```
df.tag_positions = df.tag_positions.apply(lambda x : x[0] if type(x) == list else x)
```